# About I can't use live server in vscode because it show server is started at port:

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I click "open with live-server", the vscode have no response or show "server is started at port"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLThO.png)

Comment: I know the reason, but how to make the web next to vscode like others?  Anyway, to browser this address is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

just open in your web browser this address http://localhost:8080
and the magic will happen

Comment: think you, but how to make the web next to vscode like others, modify some settings?

Comment: find in settings for Live Server extension in VSCode this one: Live Server › Settings: Custom Browser

Answer (score 0):

since its showing that your server started on 8080 so you have to use localhost:8080 on your web browser

Comment: hey if you want to make it live then download live server extension from vs code @叶翎汐